# Marketing Cloud - How to check if Email has been sent from other Journey already?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I am building a Journey in which, before the email activity is triggered:

I have to check if the subscriber already received an email from one of 9 other journeys. If already email is sent from one of those journeys, email activity should not occur.

How to check this in the Journey? Do I have to modify 9 Journeys now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that you could possibly do without modifying journeys:

1. Create an Auto suppression list and associate it to the sender profile or send classification used in the email sends.
2. Create an Automation that queries the sent and job data view in conjunction to check if the email has been sent.
3. If yes, populate a data extension with the result of the query from the above step, include email address and subscriber key.
4. Use data extract and file transfer to populate the auto suppression list created in Step 1 with this data.
5. Once a subscriber is in this list, the subscriber will be excluded from the send automatically.

Depending on your business needs, you can run the automation accordingly. Hopefully, it makes sense.